# Why do we call all http services 'Web Api/Web Service'?

Tags: http, web-services

I noticed that http services that receive and return JSON are called 'Web Api/Web Service' in many articles/book/documentation etc.

But isn't the Web (World Wide Web) basically about websites, html and web browsers? To simply define, browsers retrieve HTML files from a server, renders and present them to end users.

So why are http services that receive and return JSON called 'Web Api/Web Service'?
This service does not return HTML or it's response does not rendered by browsers. This API may not even be used by a website. For example, it may have been written only for another business microservice or mobile applications.

Comment: [The W3C defines "web service" in their glossary](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/NOTE-ws-gloss-20040211/#webservice), though that's from 2004, during the dark, dark days of SOAP. Al;so, it helps to keep-in-mind that [anything that calls itself RESTful _probably isn't_ actually RESTful](https://steveklabnik.com/writing/nobody-understands-rest-or-http).

Comment: Thanks, I was asking the question referring to http services that return JSON, whether RESTful or not. However, it might be better if I remove the term 'RESTful' so that the question has a single focus.

Comment: @Dai About W3C's definition: 'Web' is related to HTTP and they defined 'Web Service' in terms of SOAP. This is really confusing and leads to inconsistency of concepts.

Comment: Well, _the web_ **is** HTTP - if it isn't HTTP then it isn't the web. What's confusing about that? (i.e. "if it's accessible over HTTP (`http:`, `https:`, HTTP/2, HTTP/3, QUIC+HTTP, etc) then it's part of "the web").

Comment: Yes web is HTTP. But W3C's 'Web Service' definition is SOAP. So W3C's 'Web Service' definition is confusing. How can 'Web Service' about SOAP while 'Web' is http?

Comment: You can ignore the SOAP part now. It isn't 2004 anymore (when that document was written).

Comment: Also, the idea that all http services are web services is confusing, which is what I mean in the question. I think Web Services are http services that serve browsers and return HTML. Not all http services return HTML or serve browsers. For example, I don't understand why a service that returns JSON is called a web service. For example, it only serves a microservice or android application, where is the web in this?

Comment: A service accessible over HTTP that returns JSON is a web-service because it's accessible over HTTP. There is no requirement that a web-browser be used to browse the web; on the contrary, the W3C's specs have always referred to "user-agents" instead.

Comment: @dai Could you please post an answer, including the wrong parts of the definitions and arguments I made in my question? It would be better for clarity.